# Getting fixed T-SQL for Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created the following T-SQL code in SQL Server Management Studio. In this, I am trying to acheive items details from **each** Customer Management station database which is in  remote server 770Main.

All the customer databases have same database structure/design. But there are about 60 customers. So using T-SQL I put the entire script into a template string, with {dbname} placeholders and execute `@SQLSCRIPT`within a loop. When I execute this I am getting Warning:

> Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

However, when I execute SQL template script (See Below) separately for one customer only it runs absolutely fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vend.contact
                   ,C.customername
                    ,item.vendoritem
                    ,item.description1
                    ,item.issuecost
                    ,bin.station
                    ,ST.CRIBSTTYPE
                    ,R.RBSTTYPE
                    ,Bin.packQty
                    ,item.orderqty
                    ,weeklysales.lastweeksales
                    ,weeklysales.wtdsales
                    ,st.cribmin 
                    ,st.cribmax
                    ,R.MYMIN
                    ,R.MYMAX
                    ,acbin.binqoh [AutoCrib QOH]
    FROM   [770main].{dbname}.dbo.bin Bin 

       LEFT OUTER JOIN [770main].{dbname}.dbo.item Item 
                    ON bin.item = item.code 
        inner join [770main].{dbname}.dbo.release as rls on rls.itemid=item.code and item.vendor=rls.vendorid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [770main].{dbname}.dbo.company Company 
                    ON bin.aspprocessed = company.aspprocessed 
        left join (select sum(onhand) binqoh,aspprocessed,item from [770main].{dbname}.dbo.bin where station not like ''ods%''  group by aspprocessed,item ) acbin 
                    on acbin.item = Item.code and acbin.aspprocessed = Company.aspprocessed
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [770main].{dbname}.dbo.vend Vend 
                    ON item.vendor = vend.myno 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN customer C 
                    ON C.customercode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  = vend.contact collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

        left join 
    (select productcode
           , ordh.companyid
           ,sum( CASE WHEN  (invoicedate >= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate())-1, 0) and invoicedate <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6)) 
                   THEN (ordhl.NetPrice*ordhl.shippedquantity/ coalesce(ordhl.UnitOfMeasurePriceFactor,1) / coalesce(ordh.CurrencyRate,1))
                 ELSE Null END) lastweeksales
                 ,
        sum( CASE WHEN   (invoicedate >= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0) and invoicedate <= getdate())
                 THEN (ordhl.NetPrice*ordhl.shippedquantity/ coalesce(ordhl.UnitOfMeasurePriceFactor,1) / coalesce(ordh.CurrencyRate,1))
                 ELSE Null END) wtdsales
     from orderhistory ordh inner join orderhistoryline ordhl on
     ordh.CompanyID = ordhl.companyid and
     ordh.ordernumber = ordhl.ordernumber
     where 
     (invoicedate >= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate())-1, 0) and invoicedate <= getdate()) and
     ShippedQuantity <> 0 and ordh.CompanyID = ''002''
     group by productcode, ordh.companyid
     ) weeklysales on
     weeklysales.productcode = item.vendoritem 
    left join [770main].{dbname}.dbo.station s on bin.station = s.myno
    FULL JOIN STNMM St ON Bin.Item=St.ITEM 
    FULL JOIN ROBOMM R ON Bin.Item=R.ITEM
    WHERE 
    C.COMPANYID = ''002''
    GROUP BY vend.contact
                   ,C.customername
                    ,item.vendoritem
                    ,bin.station
                    ,ST.CRIBSTTYPE
                    ,R.RBSTTYPE
                    ,Bin.packQty
                    ,item.orderqty
                    ,weeklysales.lastweeksales
                    ,weeklysales.wtdsales
                    ,st.cribmin 
                    ,st.cribmax
                    ,R.MYMIN
                    ,R.MYMAX
                    ,item.description1
                    ,acbin.binqoh 
                    ,item.issuecost
```

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



IF (object_id('TMPProductbyCustomer')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE TMPProductbyCustomer
print('dropped')


END



DECLARE @sql_script VARCHAR(max)

DECLARE @template VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @Dbname varchar(100)
DECLARE @table table(id int identity(1,1),dbname varchar(100))

insert into @table

SELECT 'Abipa'
union select 'ascoac'
union SELECT 'BourgaultE' 
UNION SELECT 'Avcorp'
UNION SELECT 'Blackcat'

DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 1
DECLARE @END int = (select count(*) from @table)

CREATE table TMPProductbyCustomer ( 
CustomerID varchar(6)
,CompanyName       varchar(100) null
,ItemVendorItem    varchar(100)
,Decription1 varchar(35) null
,IssueCost money 
,Station varchar(4)
,CribStationType int null
,RoboStationType int null
,PackQty int
,ORDERQTY int 
,LastWeekSales money null
,WTDSales money null
,CRIBMIN int null
,CRIBMAX int null
,MYMIN int null
,MYMAX int null
,OnHand int 
     )
WHILE @COUNTER <= @END

BEGIN

set @DBNAME = (select dbname from @table where ID = @COUNTER )
set @template ='
WITH STNMM (item, station, cribsttype,name,packqty,onhand,burnqty,cribmin,cribmax)

AS
(
    select
    bin.item
    ,bin.station
    ,station.[type] AS CRIBSTTYPE
    ,station.name
    ,bin.packqty
    ,bin.onhand
    ,bin.burnqty
    ,bin.minimum as cribmin
    ,bin.maximum as cribmax
    from [770main].{dbname}.dbo.bin as bin
    left join [770main].{dbname}.dbo.station as station on bin.station=station.myno
    where station.[type] <> 6
),
ROBOMM (item, station, RBSTTYPE,name,pkgqty,mymin,mymax)
AS
(
    SELECT 
    MM.ITEM
    ,MM.STATION
    ,station.[type] as RBSTTYPE
    ,STATION.NAME
    ,MM.PKGQTY
    ,MM.MYMIN
    ,MM.MYMAX
    FROM [770MAIN].{dbname}.DBO.ROBOMINMAX AS MM
    LEFT JOIN [770MAIN].{dbname}.DBO.STATION AS STATION ON MM.STATION=STATION.MYNO
    WHERE station.[type] = 6 )

INSERT INTO TMPProductbyCustomer SELECT DISTINCT vend.contact
               ,C.customername
               ,item.vendoritem
                ,item.description1
                ,item.description2
                ,item.issuecost
                ,bin.station
                ,ST.CRIBSTTYPE
                ,R.RBSTTYPE
                ,Bin.packQty
                ,item.orderqty
                ,weeklysales.lastweeksales
                ,weeklysales.wtdsales
                ,st.cribmin 
                ,st.cribmax
                ,R.MYMIN
                ,R.MYMAX
                ,acbin.binqoh [AutoCrib QOH]

FROM   [770main].{dbname}.dbo.bin Bin 

   LEFT OUTER JOIN [770main].{dbname}.dbo.item Item 
                ON bin.item = item.code 
    inner join [770main].{dbname}.dbo.release as rls on rls.itemid=item.code and item.vendor=rls.vendorid
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [770main].{dbname}.dbo.company Company 
                ON bin.aspprocessed = company.aspprocessed 
    left join (select sum(onhand) binqoh,aspprocessed,item from [770main].{dbname}.dbo.bin where station not like ''ods%''  group by aspprocessed,item ) acbin 
                on acbin.item = Item.code and acbin.aspprocessed = Company.aspprocessed
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [770main].{dbname}.dbo.vend Vend 
                ON item.vendor = vend.myno 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN customer C 
                ON C.customercode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  = vend.contact collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
LEFT JOIN 
(select productcode
  , ordh.companyid
,       sum( CASE WHEN  (invoicedate >= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate())-1, 0) and invoicedate <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6)) 
               THEN (ordhl.NetPrice*ordhl.shippedquantity/ coalesce(ordhl.UnitOfMeasurePriceFactor,1) / coalesce(ordh.CurrencyRate,1))
             ELSE 0 END) lastweeksales
             ,
    sum( CASE WHEN   (invoicedate >= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0) and invoicedate <= getdate())
             THEN (ordhl.NetPrice*ordhl.shippedquantity/ coalesce(ordhl.UnitOfMeasurePriceFactor,1) / coalesce(ordh.CurrencyRate,1))
             ELSE 0 END) wtdsales
 from orderhistory ordh inner join orderhistoryline ordhl on
 ordh.CompanyID = ordhl.companyid and
 ordh.ordernumber = ordhl.ordernumber
 where 
 (invoicedate >= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate())-1, 0) and invoicedate <= getdate()) and
 ShippedQuantity <> 0 and ordh.CompanyID = ''002''
 group by productcode, ordh.companyid
 ) weeklysales on
 weeklysales.productcode = item.vendoritem 
left join [770main].{dbname}.dbo.station s on bin.station = s.myno
FULL JOIN STNMM St ON Bin.Item=St.ITEM 
FULL JOIN ROBOMM R ON Bin.Item=R.ITEM
WHERE 
C.COMPANYID = ''002''
GROUP BY vend.contact
               ,C.customername
                ,item.vendoritem
                ,bin.station
                ,ST.CRIBSTTYPE
                ,R.RBSTTYPE
                ,Bin.packQty
                ,item.orderqty
                ,weeklysales.lastweeksales
                ,weeklysales.wtdsales
                ,st.cribmin 
                ,st.cribmax
                ,R.MYMIN
                ,R.MYMAX
                ,item.description1
                ,acbin.binqoh 
                ,item.issuecost
'
SET @SQL_SCRIPT = REPLACE(@template, '{dbname}', @DBNAME)

EXECUTE (@sql_script)

set @COUNTER = @COUNTER +1

end

select * from TMPProductbyCustomer
```

Comment: @SQL Surfer I have tried your suggestion but now I come across this error: Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query.

Comment: What I believe or feel is the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options are required to be separately set (either ON/OFF) for the two servers that I am utilizing in my query. One is local and other is remote 770Main. Not sure how exactly I should apply this as my problem now is I am joining the tables from these two servers in one query.

Comment: I am aware of so many questions out there already regarding this warning already but I have different scenario here as I am trying to fetch data in one query from local and remote servers simultaneously.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sorry let me try to reduce the code lil bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of code.

I notice this line:

```
sum( 
    CASE 
    WHEN  (invoicedate >= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate())-1, 0) 
    and invoicedate <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6)) 
    THEN (ordhl.NetPrice*ordhl.shippedquantity/ 
    coalesce(ordhl.UnitOfMeasurePriceFactor,1)/ 
    coalesce(ordh.CurrencyRate,1))
    ELSE Null 
 END) lastweeksales
```

I suggest you change `ELSE Null` to `ELSE 0`, as long as it doesn't introduce divide by zero errors

Answer (score 1):

Just before you run the code that raises the error you can set this option for your current calling context.

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
```

You will want to make sure the null elimination is actually OK for your case as well.  This could be a valid error showing a logic problem in your queries.

Comment: This question is so common that I can see it answered on Stack overflow as far back as 2009.   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=null+values+is+eliminated      This is the last time I will reflexively answer a question on stack overflow.

Comment: If this has been answered before, the question should be closed as a duplicate

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the error is same on other questions but the scenario or cause seems to be different. Remote server is being utilized in the query